# Change text color in DataGridVIewComboBoxCell

Tags: datagridview, colors, c#-4.0

I've been trying for awhile to find out how to change the color of the text in the combo box cell. So far all I've managed to do with Style.BackColor and ForeColor is change the color of the background and text respectively in the drop down box. I want to change the text color in the thing with the down arrow that you click on to make the drop down box, whatever its called.

Any ideas?

Thanks guys!

Isaac

Comment: I'll also accept as a solution any way of changing the color of the border of the cell, or any way to make the cell stand out amongst all the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it has to do with windows 7 combo box styles. You have to set the style of the combo box to flat for the forecolor to change the text color. But it doesn't look like a comobo box anymore if you do this. The only solution is to use some of the drawing libraries to draw your own text over the box.

Comment: Indeed. Setting style to flat will make the forecolor/backcolor appear even when not dropped down. Thanks.